# Resizing JPanel containing a JscrollPane having a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

[image]

I have a `JPanel`(named mainJP) which has a few buttons and labels (uses `BorderLayout`). Next it adds another `JPanel` (named JP1) and inside it a `ScrollPane` with a `JTable`. I want to be able to resize JP2 and in turn all its child components (`ScrollPane` and `JTable`).  So that I can see few more rows of the `JTable` without having to scroll. Also inorder to resize JP1, other siblings of JP1 should adjust themselves. Not sure how to achieve that.

As the image shows I already have a few features implemented - to entirely delete JP1, to expand/collapse JP1 view, to delete and add rows in the `JTable`.

So basically I want to be able to drag the mouse at bottom border of JP1 to vertically increase the size of JP1 and its child components (`ScrollPane` and `JTable`).

As described in a few of the below solutions, I am still confused at which level should I incorporate a `JSpiltPane` - as it allows only adding 2 components. I think all the JP1 should be in the `JSplitPane`. However there can be more than one JP1 components and they are dynamically added.

Comment: Are you asking how to make a JPanel resizable with a mouse drag, or are you asking how to get the child components to resize with the JPanel when it does expand?

Comment: Swing has a component for that, called [JSplitPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JSplitPane.html). Read more about it in [How to Use Split Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/splitpane.html).

Comment: Thank for your responses. I want to know how to resize a JPanel and all its children depending on mouse drag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add extra components to the JSplitPane is easy.  Put a JPanel in each pane you want to show your components, then add the components to this panel -- you can customize the layout as needed.

Something like this will put a JSplitPane in an already create JFrame, add a JPanel to each Pane, and then add some JLabels to the left side, a JTextField to the right.  The splitpane will expand to the size of the JFrame it's in.

```
JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane();
JPanel leftPanel = new JPanel();
JPanel rightPanel = new JPanel();
JLabel label1 = new JLabel();
JLabel label2 = new JLabel();
JTextField textField = new JTextField();
GridBagConstraints gBC = new GridBagConstraints();

getContentPane().setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
leftPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
rightPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

// I'm not going to bother doing any layout of the label or textfield here
leftPanel.add(label1, new GridBagConstraints());
leftPanel.add(label2, new GridBagConstraints());
rightPanel.add(textField, new GridBagConstraints());

splitPane.setLeftComponent(leftPanel);
splitPane.setRightComponent(rightPanel);

gBC.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
gBC.weightx = 1.0;
gBC.weighty = 1.0;
getContentPane().add(splitPane, gBC);

pack();
```

Comment: I like this answer and thank you for posting the code sample. However the different components added in the `JSplitPane` need to be resizable as well. So all the JP1 components (please refer image) added to the JSplitPane need to be resizable and resizing one component requires all others to adjust accordingly. Any idea on how to add all these components in the `JSplitPane` and how to resize others if one is resized? Sample code of the solution would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Well, I'm not a code factory, so you will have to learn some of this on your own.  You will notice I added a JPanel to each side of the JSplitPane for you, and set it's layout manager to GridBagLayout.  I did this so you could add further components to it like I did with the JLabel or JTextField.  You will probably want to use GridBagConstraints and play with the 'fill', 'weightx' and 'weighty' to get the desired resizing you want.

Answer (score 0):

These are two different problems.  Resizing a JPanel on a mouse drag -- the easiest way for you is going to be to use two nested JSplitPanes.  You would use one so you can drag horizontally, and another to drag vertically.

Alternatively, if you don't want split panes, you can try something like this method and create a custom JPanel.  The borders are there to make the effect more visible.  I personally don't like it as it's overly complicated.

```
public class ResizablePanel extends JPanel {

    private boolean drag = false;
    private Point dragLocation  = new Point();

    public  ResizablePanel() {
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED));
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        final JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                drag = true;
                dragLocation = e.getPoint();
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                drag = false;
            }
        });
        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                if (drag) {
                    if (dragLocation.getX()> getWidth()-10 && dragLocation.getY() > getHeight()-10) {
                        System.err.println("in");
                        setSize((int)(getWidth()+(e.getPoint().getX()-dragLocation.getX())),
                            (int)(getHeight()+(e.getPoint().getY()-dragLocation.getY())));
                        dragLocation = e.getPoint();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        f.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        f.getContentPane().add(this,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ResizablePanel();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the idea of using JSplitPanes. However my UI has mulitple JPanel components (JP1 category) which all have their child components. These JP1's can be added dynamically in the application. So could you suggest if there is a way to add multiple components to the JSplitPane?

Comment: I'll add another answer to make it easier to read.  PS, please vote up or accept my answers if they are useful to you, thanks.

Comment: Sure, I would definetely like to up Vote both your answers, but since I am new and have v low reputation I am unable to do that.

Answer (score 0):

As for the children resizing with it's parent, that one is pretty easy with GridBagLayout.

The important parts to remember in the GridBagConstraints are the fill, weightx and weighty.

You can just do something like this in your frame -- it will put a scrollpane with a JTable in it that will resize with the frame:

```
JScrollPane jScrollPane1 = new JScrollPane();
JTable jTable1 = new JTable();
GridBagConstraints gBC = new GridBagConstraints();

getContentPane().setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
jScrollPane1.setViewPortView(jTable1);

gBC.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
gBC.weightx = 1.0;
gBC.weighty = 1.0;

getContentPane().add(jScrollPane1, gBC);
```